# Flask-Babel Choose right locale using Accept-Language header

Tags: python, flask, localization, flask-babel

Say I have an application with a few translations available:

```
AVAILABLE_LOCALES = ['en_US', 'en_EN', 'de_AT']
```

and I'd like to select the most appropriate according to the `Accept-Language` header.

#### Using request.accept_languages.best_match

To get the locale, I would write something like this:

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is not None:
        return user.locale
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(AVAILABLE_LOCALES)
```

The issue is if a user agent asks for `de_DE`, the match fails and the choice falls back on the default value (english), while I would rather get `de_AT`, obviously.

Note: the example in the [doc page](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/) reads

```
return request.accept_languages.best_match(['de', 'fr', 'en'])
```

but this does not allow two different versions of the same language (`en_EN`, `en_US`).

#### Using negotiate_locale

In this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/450), someone suggests the use of Babel's `negotiate_locale` function:

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is not None:
        return user.locale
    preferred = [x.replace('-', '_') for x in request.accept_languages.values()]
    return negotiate_locale(preferred, AVAILABLE_LOCALES)
```

But AFAIU, this does not fix all use cases. Only the case where the user agent asks for `['de_AT', 'de']` when available locales are `['en_US', 'en_EN', 'de_DE']`. But not the other way around:

```
negotiate_locale(['de_AT', 'de'], ['en_US', 'en_EN', 'de_DE'])  # returns de_DE
negotiate_locale(['de_DE', 'de'], ['en_US', 'en_EN', 'de_AT'])  # returns None
```

The first works because a [hardcoded list of aliases](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/blob/d277c12319ceeb6066898fca64a0381ca5f5a40c/babel/core.py#L79) makes `de` point to `de_DE`.

Also, the case where a browser would only send `de_AT` and not `de` is broken as well, but I'm not sure this is a common configuration (see next paragraph).

Is there any reliable way to deal with this?

#### Typical values in modern browsers?

As a subquestion, I'd like to know what kind of values I can expect from a modern browser.

Is it safe to assume a modern browser, unless wrongly user-customized, will send an `Accept-Language` of the form [lang+territory, lang] like this?

```
['en-US', 'en']
```

Also, I tried my Firefox version to see what I'd get, and it is a bit surprising.

The locale on my system is French:

```
locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The `about:config` page says:

```
general.useragent.locale: en-US
intl.accept_languages: fr, fr-fr, en-us, en
```

and when I connect to my test Flask app, I get

```
print(request.accept_languages.values())
# ['en_US', 'en']
```

so the suggested `@babel.localeselector` would return an English locale.

I get the same values using Chromium.

Are my browsers misconfigured?